# User information is not persistenting to Oracle Database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have done this is the past with mySQL but I need to use Oracle:

This is a very simple register user:

application.properties

```
#Oracle database setup
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@999.999.999.11:1521:d3SID
spring.datasource.username=userName
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

server.port = 4000
```

UserInformation model

```
@Entity
public class UserInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    @Min(2) @Max(15)
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof UserInformation)) {
            return false;
        }

        UserInformation that = (UserInformation) o;

        return id.equals(that.id);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Applicant{" + "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' + ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' + ", userName='" + userName + '\'' + ", password='" +
               password + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

JPA repo

```
public interface UserLoginRepo extends JpaRepository<UserInformation, Long> {}
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserInformation registerUser(@RequestBody UserInformation user){

        return userService.save(user);
    }
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM USERINFORMATION;` nothing displays.

From my understanding I should not need to set up JPA config since I am doing it in `applications.properties`.

Comment: Where do you run your `select` and why if you're using JPA? Why did you leave out the relevant parts? If nothing displays, is there nothing to display or are you just swallowing exceptions?

Comment: @Kayaman I prefer to use JPA and I `public interface UserLoginRepo extends JpaRepository<UserInformation, Long> {}` has CRUD for me so no need to write a select statement.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. You're running the select outside of the program to check if something was saved. Anyways, check your logs and run it through a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check if the UserInformation object is coming from request body? As I know you shouldn't use **"@RequestBody"**, just put **"UserInformation user"** must be in the parameters.

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.